# Insert error in a Mysql query Flask web app

Tags: python, mysql

My app.py code :

```
@app.route('/register' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username =%s', (username, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            msg = "Account already exists !"
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Invalid email adress !'

        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            msg = 'Username must contain only characters and numbers !'
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            msg = 'Please fill the form !'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL ,%s,%s,%s', (username, password, email, ))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered !'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        msg = 'Please fill out the form !'
    return render_template('register.html' , msg = msg)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

This is the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\app.py", line 68, in register
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL ,%s,%s,%s', (username, password, email, ))
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "D:\Code\spoof\webapp2\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
```

I am using python 3.10.2 and flask 2.2.2 in my virtual environment. And I am using Visual Studio IDE. It seems like I am doing something wrong in the MYSQL query. can you guys tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Its always better to name the columns in an INSERT query, otherwise the order the columns were created in is used (or the order they have recently been change to, which can really mess you up) If that order does not match the order you put the data fields in, you will at best get data in the wrong column and at worst break the query

Comment: Thanks a lot @RiggsFolly. please post this as an answer so I can verify it.

Comment: Also looks like you have missed the closing `)` from the `VALUES ()` part of the query, or rather put it in the wrong place i.e. the end of the call `))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket in your `cursor.execute()` statement and the last comma is not needed. Also, you can specify the column names.

Here is a solution with the query and values separated into variables for readability:

```
sql_query = 'INSERT INTO accounts(username, password, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
vals = (username, password, email)
cursor.execute(sql_query, vals)
```